# MATLAB - how to simulate sinusoidal free breathing curve?

Tags: matlab, signals, trigonometry, waveform, wave

I am trying to model some breathing patterns and need some insights on how to simulate free breathing and irregular breathing on MATLAB.

The scope of this project does not need to reflect closely to actual breathing curves, such as:https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Respiratory-motion-graph-of-a-volunteer-performing-the-isovolume-maneuver-The-opposite_fig6_319036447
and is assumed to be a simple, sinusoidal one.

Regular breathing is trivial - I set 15 cycle per minute (CPM) as breathing rate and adjusted the period of the MATLAB sin function as needed.

As for free breathing and irregular breathing, my goals are:

Free breathing : Each inhalation/exhalation will have separate randomness to it (with respect to amplitude and period), with methods of introducing randomness being in question.

Irregular breathing : Consider this to be a much more chaotic version of the above 'free breathing' Cough, and sudden breath cease are all game.

My current lead for Free breathing is an iterative method (adding different sin waves at the end value of last sin wave)

as for Irregular breathing, I am thinking of convolving a sin function with square functions with funky periods, until I obtain something that I like - although so far this method does not seem to have enough 'randomness' like coughing or breath cease..

If anyone has some experience or insight into wave generation, I'd love to hear some ideas on how to approach this!

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions:

1. If you want to set a sine of 15 cycles per minute, you must convert these 15 cycles to hertz. and search for the word "How do I generate a sine wave at x-hertz?"
2. Free breathing & Irregular breathing, I think you should study frequency and amplitude modulation to modulate the sine wave into different pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, as for your suggestion 1. I established in my question that this is trivial. As for 2. the suggestion ("you should study frequency and amplitude modulation") is vague. Any specific direction you want me to look?